# ffmpeg says "ratecontrol_init: can't open stats file" when doing 2-pass encoding

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion

I am running the following commands for two-pass encoding with ffmpeg and x264:

```
ffmpeg -t 5 -i Meridian.avi -filter:v scale=-2:240 -b:v 0.20M -passlogfile Meridian-240 -pass 1 -f null /dev/null
ffmpeg -t 5 -i Meridian.avi -filter:v scale=-2:240 -b:v 0.20M -passlogfile Meridian-240 -pass 2 Meridian-240.mp4
```

However, when I run the second command, I get this error:

```
ffmpeg version 4.1.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.5.0 (Homebrew gcc 5.5.0_4)
  configuration: --prefix=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.1.3-with-options --enable-shared --enable-hardcoded-tables --cc=gcc-5 --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --disable-htmlpages --enable-libvmaf --enable-version3
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, avi, from 'Meridian.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.26.101
    timecode        : 00:00:17;12
  Duration: 00:01:00.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 887782 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: ffv1 (FFV1 / 0x31564646), yuv420p, 3840x2160, 888395 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24 tbn, 24 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (ffv1 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x202f180] using SAR=640/639
[libx264 @ 0x202f180] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x202f180] ratecontrol_init: can't open stats file
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
Conversion failed!
```

So basically it says:

> ratecontrol_init: can't open stats file

Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Specify the encoder in the first (and second, to be safe) pass.

```
ffmpeg -t 5 -i Meridian.avi -filter:v scale=-2:240 -c:v libx264 -b:v 0.20M -passlogfile Meridian-240 -pass 1 -f null /dev/null
```

When no encoder is specified, ffmpeg chooses the default encoder of the output format. For null, it's not x264 or any actual encoder. So there is no first pass carried out.

No point specifying a productive muxer, as those CPU cycles are just wasted.

Comment: True, that's closer to the actual issue.